# How do I add extra slides to this pure CSS text rotator?

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty adding more slides to this text rotator. When I have four slides, everything works fine.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/1/

HTML

```
<ul class="rotator">
  <li>Otterbox is the #1 selling case for smartphones in the US</li>
  <li>65 day warranty</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li>All orders placed by 11 am MT are shipped that day!</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.rotator > li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 0s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 5s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 10s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 15s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  5% { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  30% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

However, when I add another slide and update the CSS, I notice that some slides overlap each other.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/

HTML

```
<ul class="rotator">
  <li>Otterbox is the #1 selling case for smartphones in the US</li>
  <li>65 day warranty</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li>test 4</li>
  <li>All orders placed by 11 am MT are shipped that day!</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.rotator > li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 0s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 5s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 10s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 15s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: loop 20s 20s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  5% { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  30% { opacity: 1; }
  35% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I was wondering if anybody could help me figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every slide you add, you need to increase duration by 5s. So if you have 5 slides, your duration needs to be 25s. Now your keyframes will display every slide longer though, because they are percentage values of 25s now instead of 20s before, so you need to adjust those as well.

Here is the updated fiddle with 5 slides: http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/50/

Updated CSS

```
.rotator > li {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(255, 0, 255, .4);
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: loop 25s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  5%,20% { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll play around with it. Can you explain what the last few lines are doing? `@-webkit-keyframes loop` Also, I tried adding a sixth slide, but couldn't get it to work. Can you explain what I'm missing here? http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/51/

Comment: For a sixth slide just add another .rotator > li:nth-child(6) with a delay of 25s.

in the keyframes, you need to change the 20% according to the amount of slides you have. 5 slides: 100% / 5 = 20%. 6 slides: 100% / 6 = 16.67% and so on, assuming you still want to display each slide for 5 seconds

Alternatively, you probably don't like it because you wrote "Pure CSS", but here is a JQuery Alternative, where you can add as many slides as you want. http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/38/

Comment: Here it is with 6 slides, using a keyframe at 16.67%.
http://jsfiddle.net/6eq5fvrn/52/

The 3% and 20% you can change however you want to, depending on how long you want the transition to be. Lowering the 3% will shorten the fade in transition, lowering the 20% to anywhere between that and 16.67% will shorten the fade out transition

Comment: Such a huge help. Thank you!